# I can't run any .x86 games

Tags: games

I downloaded [this game](http://gamejolt.com/games/maximum-velocity/33960), and it simply does nothing when I try to run it. No error, nothing.

I tried to see what was wrong by running it with the command "ldd" and it gave me this:

> wayne@wayne-iMac:~$ ldd /home/wayne/Downloads/MaximumVelocityLinux/MaximumVelocity.x86
>       linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xf76e3000)
>       libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0xf76bf000)
>       libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0xf76a3000)
>       librt.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0xf7699000)
>       libGLU.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLU.so.1 (0xf7626000)
>       libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 (0xf7594000)
>       libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0xf7460000)
>       libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0xf744d000)
>       libXcursor.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXcursor.so.1 (0xf7441000)
>       libXrandr.so.2 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXrandr.so.2 (0xf7436000)
>       libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0xf73f0000)
>       libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xf73d3000)
>       libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xf7225000)
>       /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf76e6000)
>       libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0xf713c000)
>       libexpat.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0xf7113000)
>       libglapi.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglapi.so.0 (0xf70fa000)
>       libXdamage.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1 (0xf70f6000)
>       libXfixes.so.3 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3 (0xf70f0000)
>       libX11-xcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1 (0xf70ec000)
>       libxcb-glx.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-glx.so.0 (0xf70d4000)
>       libxcb-dri2.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri2.so.0 (0xf70ce000)
>       libxcb-dri3.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri3.so.0 (0xf70ca000)
>       libxcb-present.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-present.so.0 (0xf70c6000)
>       libxcb-sync.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-sync.so.1 (0xf70be000)
>       libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0xf709c000)
>       libxshmfence.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxshmfence.so.1 (0xf7099000)
>       libXxf86vm.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1 (0xf7093000)
>       libdrm.so.2 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2 (0xf7084000)
>       libXrender.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1 (0xf7078000)
>       libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0xf7074000)
>       libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0xf706d000)

I installed all the libraries but it still doesn't run.

iMac (21.5-inch, Mid 2011)

Processor 2.5 GHz Intel Core i5

Graphics AMD Radeon HD 6750M 512 MB

Memory 4 GB 1333 MHz DDR3

Comment: What does sudo apt-get install libx11-6 return?
Adding :i386 (sudo apt-get install libx11-6:i386) installs the x86 variant.

Comment: wayne@wayne-iMac:~$ sudo apt-get install libx11-6
[sudo] password for wayne: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libx11-6 is already the newest version.
libx11-6 set to manually installed.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gtk3-engines-unico libtimezonemap1
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 46 not upgraded.

Comment: Even after doing sudo apt-get install libx11-6:i386 it doesn't work.

Comment: And it still shows libX11.so.6 => not found?

Comment: These are the only ones that say, not found.
 libGLU.so.1 => not found, 
 libGL.so.1 => not found, 
 libXext.so.6 => not found, 
 libXcursor.so.1 => not found, 
 libXrandr.so.2 => not found, 
The rest doesn't fit here.

Comment: What graphics card/chip do you have? This will help anyone trying to answer to know which drivers you'll be using. Most of those libraries will come from your driver.

Comment: I meant for you to include these details in your question.

Comment: Ok, I added it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install the relevant libraries in 32-bit.

For example, "sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa:i386" should get rid of the "libGLU.so.1 => not found".

With some effort I'm sure you can find the packages for the other libraries.

Comment: Even after installing all the libraries it doesn't work.

Comment: has anything changed? I assume you're running in from the command line - what prints out there?

Comment: I posted it above.

Comment: Not from ldd, when you actually try to run the game